# Sorting consistency of dynamically created IDs on DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

My application successfully creates elements and assigns them different (increasing) IDs.

Now my issue relies when the user deletes these elements (because they have the option to delete as well as create), the consistency of these IDs get broken therefore my application doesn't run well.

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZW6vH/) represents what I have so far. Just a textbox that appends its value and a few other elements inside a `collapsible` as many times as the user wants (For some reason my fiddle doesn't increment the `alert` value, but it works fine on my platform).

SCRIPT (Sorry the txt variable is too long)

```
$('#Add').click(function () {
if ($("#MedNameStren").val() != "") {
    var value = $("#MedNameStren").val();
    var noOfMeds = $('#NoOfMedicines').val();
    //to check current value
    alert(noOfMeds);
    var text = '<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-iconpos="left" data-content-theme="e">' + '<h2>' + desc + '</h2>' + '<div class="ui-grid-a">' +          '<div class="ui-block-a" style="width:25%; margin-right:3%;">' + '<input id="quantity' + noOfMeds + '" class="quantity" type="text" placeholder="Quantity" />' + '</div>' + '<div class="ui-block-b" style="width:70%; margin-right:2%;"">' + '<textarea id="directions' + noOfMeds + '" class="directions" cols="40" rows="4" placeholder="Directions given by your GP." ></textarea>' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '<button key="' + vpid + '">Remove</button>' + '</div>';
    $("#medListLi").append(text);
    $('button').button();
    $('#medListLi').find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
    $('#medListLi li').listview("refresh");
    $('#medListLi').trigger("create");
    document.getElementById("manuallyName").value = "";

    noOfMeds++
    $("#NoOfMedicines").val(noOfMeds);
}
else {
         alert('Please Provide Medicine Name')
}
});
```

I am using a counter that neatly increments the ids of `quantity` and `description` like:

`quantity0`
`quantity1`
`quantity2`
..and so on, but once the following script is called...

```
//Deletes colapsible sets (Medicines) from the selected List
$('#medListLi').on('click', 'button', function (el) {
$(this).closest('div[data-role=collapsible]').remove();
var key = $(this).attr('key');
localStorage.removeItem(key);

var noOfMeds = $('#NoOfMedicines').val();
noOfMeds--
$("#NoOfMedicines").val(noOfMeds);
//location.reload();
});
```

depending on which element (`collapsible`) is deleted, the IDs stop being consistent. For example if the `collapsible` with `id="quantity1"` is deleted then the counter will go back to 1 (currently 2) and on the next addition the respective `collapsible` will get an `id` that's already taken, and unfortunately I don't need this to happen.

Maybe I'm making this sound more complicated that it is, but will appreciate any suggestions or ideas to solve this issue (if possible).

If more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Do you actually need the id's on those elements? All elements already have an index that make them uniquely selectable.

Comment: you assume count and id are the same in your code, but you don't want that assumption in real-life. solution: don't use IDs like that, or keep track of count and id separately.

Comment: Well the next bit of the application (when `Submit` is pressed) all the information has to go to `sessionStorage` in JSON form, so I need a way to get the values from all the `quantities` and `directions`. Maybe I should approach this in a different way?

Comment: Do you need ids to be used later?

Comment: @Omar, Sort of, I will only need to use them once, after the user `Submits` the form the values inside the textboxes gets called by their `ids` and stored in sessionStorage in JSON format.

Comment: whenever you hits add, you reset that var to zero and nothing is being added `var noOfMeds = $('#NoOfMedicines').val();`.

Comment: Yup, I noticed that on my fiddle, but no worries now. I have solved it by playing around with some functions that I already had on my application. I just needed to sleep on the problem to come up with a solution lol. Thank you for your time and effort to help though :)

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ZW6vH/1/

Comment: Thank you :) however this was the least of my problems, hehe but everything is solved now! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was brought to my attention that creating and deleting dynamic `IDs` can be done but keeping up with consistency of these `IDs` can be very tricky to work around it.

I've solved my own problem by simply creating a function that would keep count of the `IDs` from the amount of `collapsibles` inside my `list` and "renewing" the `ID` numbers on each `Add` and `Delete`.